# setting time range in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, time, range, where-clause

I am working on a dataset that contains car accidents and their time of occurrence. (the data set exists in SQL Server under the name **accident**).

I have a column that is in `date` format. I would like to extract the time from the column. Then add a new column called `lightining_period` label the time as **daytime** or **nighttime**. My problem is with setting a range for the times, as I get the wrong label each time I run the code.

> Different lighting periods (daytime: 6AM - 5:59PM and nighttime 6PM - 5:59AM).

[1]First I wrote this code to extract the time from `accident_date_time` and store it in a new column `time`.

```
create table lightiningPeriod as 
select to_char(accident_date_time,'HH:MMAM') as time
from accident.accident;
```

[2]Then, I altered the table to add the column `lightining_label` where I want to store the labels daytime/nighttime.

```
alter table lightiningPeriod add (
lightining_label varchar2(20)
);
```

[3]Finally, I used Update statement to change the values of `lightining_label` according to `time` ranges. But the tables come out wrong. I tried using **between**, **to_date**, **cast**, **convert** but none of them worked.

```
update lightiningPeriod
set lightining_label='daytime'
where time >= '06:00AM'
and time <= '5:59PM';
```

below is a sample of the output I get which shows wrong labels.

```
time    lightining_label
06:04AM daytime
11:04AM daytime
01:04AM (null)
10:04AM daytime
10:04AM daytime
04:04PM (null)
07:04PM daytime
01:04PM (null)
```

Comment: to_char ? that's oracle isn't it?

Comment: "I have a column that is in date format. I would like to extract the time from the column" - that doesn't make any sense I'm afraid.

Comment: Looks like you are doing a text to text comparison rather than time to time?

Comment: The original column is in DATE format. I am using to_char to extract the time.

Comment: tochar and varchar2 are not sql server - fix your tags. Using the wrong ones will only make the search for a solution longer and misleading. removed sql server and added oracle but you might be using something else

Comment: sorry my bad, sql developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I have solved the query doing this:

```
update lightiningPeriod
set lightining_label='daytime'
where to_char(accident_date_time, 'hh24:mi') >= '06:00'
and to_char(accident_date_time, 'hh24:mi') <= '17:59';
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `time` column is using a string type (`VARCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`) instead of `TIME`. So you compare string values instead of time values.

You can use the following using [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) to compare the string values like time values:

```
UPDATE lightiningPeriod
  SET lightining_label = CASE WHEN CONVERT(TIME, [time]) BETWEEN CONVERT(TIME, '06:00AM') AND CONVERT(TIME, '5:59PM') THEN 'daytime' ELSE 'nighttime' END
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a79bac4aebb0945cecfce601996b060c)

I recommend to store the time values on a column using [`TIME` data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql).

Comment: I made a mistake with the title. I am working on sql developer not server.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tweak on Sebastian's answer.  In SQL Server, you can use a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE lightiningPeriod
  ADD lightining_label AS (CASE WHEN CONVERT(TIME, [time]) >= CONVERT(TIME, '06:00:00') AND CONVERT(TIME, [time]) < CONVERT(TIME, '18:00:00')
                                THEN 'daytime' ELSE 'nighttime'
                           END)
```

Then the label is calculated when you query the table, so it is always correct.

Comment: sorry I put the wrong title. I am using sql developer. Can you please modify your answer to work on sql developer? thank you

Comment: @leena . . . Ask a new question and tag it appropriately.  This question already has several answers and changing the question or tags would invalidate the answers.